# How to avoid the load file dialog in IDA GUI

Tags: ida

I would like IDA to remember my default load file settings instead of presenting the [load file](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/242.shtml) dialog on every start. 
[The documentation says](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml) there is a **-T** command line switch that should take a 'file type prefix' argument and then not display the load file dialog, but I don't know what a valid 'file type prefix' would be. I tried -TPE but a warning popped up saying 'PE' was not recognized.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It expects the (beginning of the) actual type description (like `Portable executable for 80386 (PE)`), not the name of the loader plugin (like `pe.ldw`), because a loader plugin can generate different types.

So in the case of a Windows PE, any of these should work:

- `-T"Portable executable for 80386 (PE)"`
- `-TPortable`
- `-TP` (as the other types for a PE are likely starting with `Binary`, `Microsoft` or `MS-DOS`)